# Why I am not receiving data at server end by sending axios.put request

Tags: php, reactjs, web-services, axios

I am using Axios Api in reactjs.Axios.get is working fine for me but I am facing a issue with axios.put, when i send request with simple object i get the correct response but when i send request formdata i get null in response.

When i send request with simple object which is working fine:

```
  const data= {ProductName:"Dummy"};
const apiurl = `http://localhost/testapi/index.php/api/products/product`;
axios.put(apiurl, data).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Server End:

```
 public function product_post()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['ProductName'] = $this->post('ProductName');
    $this->response(
        [
            'status' => "ok",
            'message' => "Data inserted successfully",
            'info' => $data['ProductName']
        ],
        REST_Controller::HTTP_OK
    );
}
```

I am getting the correct response which "Dummy"

When i send request with Formdata which is not working fine:

```
  var data= new FormData();
data.set("ProductName","Dummy");
const apiurl = `http://localhost/testapi/index.php/api/products/product`;
await axios.put(apiurl, data).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Server End:

```
 public function product_post()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['ProductName'] = $this->post('ProductName');
    $this->response(
        [
            'status' => "ok",
            'message' => "Data inserted successfully",
            'info' => $data['ProductName']
        ],
        REST_Controller::HTTP_OK
    );
}
```

Now the response i am receiving with $data['ProductName'] is null.
One thing more i also tried to send file with formdata but got null

Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use append method to add new key and value to FormData

Change

```
  data.set("ProductName","Dummy");
```

To

```
  data.append("ProductName","Dummy");
```

Edit:

You need to specify in header that you are sending FormData, for that content-type should be multipart/form-data. Try with below code

```
   var data= new FormData();
     data.append("ProductName","Dummy");
     const config = {     
         headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
     }
     const apiurl = `http://localhost/testapi/index.php/api/products/product`;
    await axios.put(apiurl, data, config).then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Comment: I tried append instead of set i does not work i got same response:

    {status: "ok", message: "Data inserted successfully", info: null}

Comment: @Ch Mudabbir Hmmm. I updated my answer please check edit section

Comment: Actually axios.post works fine but when i use axios.put it does not work

Comment: Just change post to put it will work with my edited answer